# How to convert from pandas Series to an int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to convert times from UTC to local times for various countries.

To do this I'm searching a dataframe for the country name to find the timezone

```
if (country == "Brazil" or country == "DR-Congo" or country == "Indonesia" or country == "Kazakhstan" or country == "Russia"):
            tz = files.tz_club.loc[files.tz_club["shrt_nme"] == teamname, "summer"]
```

In this instance I am looking up a timezone for *Brazil* and `tz` prints as:

```
215   -3
Name: summer, dtype: int32
```

But when I try running it through a timedelta `adjust_time = timedelta(hours = tz)` I'm met with the following error: `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: Series`

I've tried to convert it to `int` using `tz = tz.astype(int)`, but that doesn't affect anything.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please? TIA.

**Edit:** Here is an example of what `tz_club` looks like...

```
                     team  winter  summer country        shrt_nme      á      é      í      ó      ú      ñ  count
0  Atlético de Alagoinhas      -3      -3  Brazil  Atlético de Al  False   True  False  False  False  False      1
1             Atletico GO      -3      -3  Brazil     Atletico GO  False  False  False  False  False  False      0
2             Atletico MG      -3      -3  Brazil     Atletico MG  False  False  False  False  False  False      0
```

Comment: `hours` parameter of `timedelta` function requires an integer. You instead are passing it `tz` which looks like it's spitting out a series, not a scalar/int. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding though? I'm flying a little blind since I can't see `tz_club` to understsand what `loc` is going after.

Comment: @JNevill thanks for your response. I've updated my original post to show a snippet of `tz_club`. Its looking up `Brazil` and pulling back `-3` from the `summer` column. I know its producing a `Series`, I need to know how I can convert this to an `int`.

Comment: I think your `tz` is in fact a series. Since it's like a scalar series, try doing `adjust_time = timedelta(hours = int(tz))` and I'm betting that gets around it. Note this will fail if for some reason your `tz_club` gets two entries for brazil and `loc` returns more than one int.

Comment: @JNevill that works a treat, thanks. There's no duplicates, I tried to simplify how the `loc` worked for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @JNevill in a comment, I needed to convert the `Series` inside of the timedelta itself rather than before it.

`timedelta(hours = int(tz))` works great.